# Flatlist error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.key.toString')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So I'm trying to display an array with some data in a Flatlist, this is the one I'm trying to display:

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "Name": Object {
        "Name": "John",
      },
      "key": 0.05992611071666909,
      "favNumber": 1,
      "age": 30,
    },
  ],
]
```

and this is my Flaltist:

```
       <FlatList
            data={this.state.list}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key.toString()}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 , flexGrow: hp('20%')}}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View>
                <View>
                  <Text>
                    {item.Name.Name}
                  </Text>
                  <Text>
                     {item.favNumber}
                  </Text>
                  <Text>
                    {item.age}
                  </Text>
                 </View>
               </View> 
              />
```

When I run the code it returns the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.key.toString')`, I imagine is because the data is nested in another array, but since I'm new at coding I don't really know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. But why exactly there are nested arrays there?

Comment: it's complicated, is there away to display the data without modifying it?

Comment: If there's just a single array nested, you can feed that array into data, with `data={this.state.list[0]}`. But this won't work, if you actually want to show all the arrays; in this case you need to flatten those arrays.